# How to add items in a dynamic array

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, dynamic, anonymous-types

I need make a function that return dynamic[]

This works fine for me

```
    public static dynamic[] GetDonutSeries(this Polls p)
    {
        return new dynamic[]
            {
                new {category = "Football",value = 35},
                new {category = "Basketball",value = 25},
                new {category = "Volleyball",value = 20},
                new {category = "Rugby",value = 10},
                new {category = "Tennis",value = 10}  
            };
    }
```

But I need to add items doing different operations.

Like this

```
public static dynamic[] GetDonutSeries(this Polls p)
    {
        dynamic[] result = new dynamic[]();

        foreach (PollOptions po in p.PollOptions)
        {
            result.Add(new {category = po.OptionName,value = po.PollVotes.Count});
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But I cant use .Add method for dynamic[]. How I can do it?

Comment: Does `dynamic[] result = new dynamic[]();` compiles at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array doesn't have `Add` method. It seems You are looking for a `List`

```
public static List<dynamic> GetDonutSeries(this Polls p)
{
    List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (PollOptions po in p.PollOptions)
    {
        result.Add(new { category = po.OptionName, value = po.PollVotes.Count });
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you *have to return* an array, you can use `result.ToArray()`

Comment: Thanks, very helped your answer :))